# No module name bootstrapping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello there I've tried to test a web project for app engine deployment using dev_appserver.py ./app.yaml but then this this return some error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from bootstrapping import bootstrapping
ImportError: No module named bootstrapping
```

the result should be a return of HTTP request handles

Comment: i don't see any way

Answer (score 0):

You need to install bootstrapping. Are you using virtualenv for test your project? you should run your dev_appserver.py script inside it:

```
virtualenv env --python=python3

source env/bin/activate
```

Then, you can install [bootstrapping](https://pypi.org/project/bootstrapping/) with pip:

```
pip install bootstrapping
```

And finally, create/update your requirements.txt file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Even if you project have a requirements.txt file, you'll need to install all your packages, before run your script:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```